# Input type time Should be in AM/PM After Changing System Time Format To 24 hour

Tags: html, angular

I am Using input type="time" in my form.
Problem is Whenever I change my system time format to 24 hour clock, Input type="time" considers that and removes AM/PM selection from the input.

But this should not happen.

**When my system time format is set to 24 hours it's shows**

[image]

**But i want AM/PM Format like below, even after changing system time format to 24 hours.**

[image]

Does anyone have Simple Solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `type="time"` input does not have support for hardcoding the format. It will always follow the clients locale or user-agent in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)).

The solution is either:

1. Creating your own custom input component (by creating a component that implements the ControlValueAccessor interface)
2. Use one of the many time-picker libraries avilable for Angular, such as [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples), [ngx-material-timepicker](https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker#readme) or [date-time-picker](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker)